# How to expose port from container to container on testcontainers?

Tags: java, docker, testcontainers

I want to integration test few services running on docker environment. They have to talk each other as they are connected. So I need to somehow expose port between each other. Is this setup possible using test containers library? I did not find any docks on it.

Tested app running locally, which will connect to dockerised servers:

- mysql
- backend one

To make it even harder backend one server needs to talk to mysql service.
Is this possible using testcontainers?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Are you saying that you will have say a server in docker container 1, running on port 8888 (e.g) and then running test in container2, that shall access docker 1, over port 8888?

Answer (score 5):

Testcontainers supports networks, there are [a few examples in the tests](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/8f1421ad5310f75f371804c3a3a1402b0eaab6d4/core/src/test/java/org/testcontainers/containers/NetworkTest.java#L13).

You need to first create a network (via `Network.newNetwork()`), and then use `withNetwork`/`withNetworkAliases` to "connect" your containers into the same network.

Comment: Ok. But those container will run in parallel right? But I need to block one to start before the db will be up and running. How this can be thone?

Comment: they will run the way you start them. You can order the rules, you can use `.start()` without using the rules - up to you (unlike Docker Compose). Just code your containers :)

Answer (score -1):

Generally, when network communication between containers is required, a network should be created at [docker level](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/) and containers should share it.

Things can be simplified by using `docker-compose`, which by default creates a network for all services declared in `docker-compose` file. Then containers can communicate via their service name.

I **have never used** Testcontainers project but I see in docs that has a [docker-compose module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/docker_compose/).

Quoting from above url:

> Testcontainers will spin up a small 'ambassador' container, which will
>   proxy between the Compose-managed containers and ports that are
>   accessible to your tests. This is done using a separate, minimal
>   container that runs socat as a TCP proxy.

There is also an example that you can base on, on docs url.

Comment: I hope for simpler solution than compose. But can not find valid example, which will contain cross containers communication. I will give a try a compose module.

Comment: Docker Compose is less flexible and harder to support, we recommend using the generic containers instead. See my answer on how to achieve the desired functionality